# Why is there a memcache delete at the end of this NDB put operation?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached, app-engine-ndb

I'm just experimenting with Appstats and NDB on Google App Engine.

I understand that the immediate get following the put would come from the local memory cache but why is there a memcache delete operation?

This is all the code:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Specs(ndb.Model):
    make = ndb.StringProperty()
    model = ndb.StringProperty()
    doors = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    wheels = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class Car(ndb.Model):
    _use_memcache = True
    _use_cache = True
    specs = ndb.LocalStructuredProperty(Specs)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        my_car = Car(id='some-car')
        specs = Specs(
          make = "Volvo",
          model = "240",
          doors = 5,
          wheels = 4
        )
        my_car.specs = specs
        result = my_car.put()

        my_car_by_get = result.get()

        self.response.write('Saved car')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),

], debug=True)
```

And the Appstats timeline:

[image: Appstats timeline of an NDB put operation]

Answer (score 1):

The `memcache.Delete()` is being called on every `put()` when you're using the NDB because of the automatic caching and this is by design. You can read more about the [NDB caching](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache) if you want to have a better control or different behaviour when it comes to caching.

Comment: So are you saying that, in this particular example, the sequence of operations may not be optimal but it's done like that to fit into a wider more general mechanism?

Comment: I'm saying that even if you have the simplest operation like only .put the memcache delete will be called.. it doesn't matter what you're doing before or after..

Comment: Read the ndb source code. The mc delete is there to avoid a race condition.

Comment: @Guido At least I wasn't totally wrong about the fact that it is calling the mc delete :) Would you mind writing a more valid answer and I'll delete this one :/